# Sony Xperia Z5 Compact black screen

Tags: broken-screen, sony-xperia-z

Yesterday I accidentally dropped my Sony Xperia Z5 Compact on the ground (from a height of about half a meter), and it appears to be broken since then. Details:

The screen was clearly on, but showed black. However, it still responded to touch on the places where the buttons should be. Rebooting by holding down the power button didn't work. Force shutdown by holding both the power button and the volume up button did work. When I rebooted, the screen remained black (but was turned on). It still responds to touches on certain spots where buttons should be. When trying to unlock it blindly, I found the emergency call keyboard.

I tried connecting the phone to my computer, and it recognizes the phone, but sees it as offline, or disconnected. I seem to have no way of remotely accessing it.

Is there anything else I can try without having it repaired at a retail store?

Comment: You could see the *emergency call keyboard* - wondering if black screen is a loose connection as a result of the fall. Maybe, smacking it hard will help?

Comment: @beeshyams I did not see the emergency call keyboard, I activated it by randomly touching the screen and I recognized the sound its buttons make. The screen was still black. Also, I am somewhat reluctant to smash it in fear of completely breaking it.